# Can I assign custom keyboard shortcuts for menu items in applications on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

OSX allows user to add custom keyboard shortcuts for menu items. For instance you can define a custom keyboard shortcut for "Copy" and it will work for every application that has a menu item called Copy.

Is there a way to do this for GTK and/or KDE applications?

Answer (score 3):

For KDE applications, it is possible for common keyboard shortcuts. To do this, open `systemsettings` and navigate to <kbd>Standard Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>.

For example, here I change the shortcut for "activate next tab" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (for consistency with Firefox):

[image: KDE's keybinding changer]

This changes the shortcut in most tabbed KDE applications as well as tabbed dialog boxes. You can specify up to 2 alternative shortcuts for each action.

However, this only works for common shortcuts; you can't globally specify shortcuts for arbitrary menu-item captions.

I don't think GNOME applications have any such feature. You have to change the shortcuts individually (for each application). (Generally KDE is more customizable.)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way to set an absolute keyboard shortcut for an arbitrary menu item name that will be honored by any GTK+ application?

No.

Can you set a different global shortcut for Cut/Copy/Paste?

I suspect so. I didn't do the reading, but here's two promising links: [making keyboard shortcuts in linux as uniform as the mac](http://abhidg.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/making-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux-as-uniform-as-the-mac/) and [change default/preference keyboard shortcuts like copy & paste](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1295702)

You can of course modify GTK+ applications to tweak their shortcuts. In the case of a GTK+ application whose GUI was designed with Glade, e.g. `virt-manager`, this could be ridiculously trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at xbindkeys and xdotool. Those are the automation tools which can help you to simulate certain keystrokes with customized shortcut.
By this means, though you don't really modify the original shortcuts, but you can still make your desired key combinations functional.